# Trying to create a reusable AppBar results in error "The getter 'height' was called on null."

Tags: flutter, dart

[Figured it out: Have posted the answer below. I had to implement PreferredSizeWidget]

I am trying to create a reusable AppBar Widget since my AppBar on different screens has several common properties.

Here is my AppBar code:

```
class WidgetAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  final double height;
  final String title;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  WidgetAppBar({
    @required this.height,
    @required this.title,
    this.actions,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(
        height,
      ),
      child: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.colorAppBarBackground,
        elevation: 0,
        leadingWidth: Dimens.appBarLeadingWidth,
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text(
          title,
          style: Styles.appBarTitle,
        ),
        actions: [
          for (Widget widget in actions) widget,
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is how I am using it in another Widget:

This is my build function, I haven't included my entire file.

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _logMethod = "Widget build()";
    logFlow(_screenString, _logMethod, "start");

    // UI variables
    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double safeAreaPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top +
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom;
    double appBarHeight = screenHeight / 16;
    double bodyHeight = screenHeight - (appBarHeight + safeAreaPadding);

    logFlow(_screenString, _logMethod, "end");

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          drawer: buildDrawer(
            _logMethod,
            bodyHeight,
          ),
          appBar: WidgetAppBar(
            screen: _screenString,
            parent: _logMethod,
            height: appBarHeight,
            title: Strings.screenHomeTitle,
            actions: <Widget>[
              WidgetHomeAppBarDate(
                navigationController: _navigationController,
                screen: _screenString,
                parent: _logMethod,
                dateText: _date,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          //     PreferredSize(
          //   preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(
          //     appBarHeight,
          //   ),
          //   child: AppBar(
          //     backgroundColor: Colors.colorAppBarBackground,
          //     elevation: 0,
          //     leadingWidth: Dimens.appBarLeadingWidth,
          //     centerTitle: false,
          //     title: Text(
          //       Strings.screenHomeTitle,
          //       style: Styles.appBarTitle,
          //     ),
          //     actions: <Widget>[
          //       WidgetHomeAppBarDate(
          //         navigationController: _navigationController,
          //         screen: _screenString,
          //         parent: _logMethod,
          //         dateText: _date,
          //       ),
          //     ],
          //   ),
          // ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.colorScreenBackground,
          body: buildBody(
            _logMethod,
            bodyHeight,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I get the error:

```
The getter 'height' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: height
```

I do not know what that means. Please help, I am trying to learn.

Comment: Where does `appBarHeight` come from?

Comment: @MindStudio added appBarHeight code.

Comment: @Nagual You don't have to be snarky about it, I didn't include because I didn't think it was relevant. I have added it now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

```
class WidgetAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String screen;
  final String parent;
  final double height;
  final String title;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  const WidgetAppBar({
    Key key,
    @required this.screen,
    @required this.parent,
    @required this.height,
    @required this.title,
    this.actions,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final String _logMethod = "$parent -> WidgetAppBar/build()";
    logFlow(screen, _logMethod, "start");

    logFlow(screen, _logMethod, "end");

    // Return appBar
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.colorAppBarBackground,
      elevation: 0,
      leadingWidth: Dimens.appBarLeadingWidth,
      centerTitle: false,
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: Styles.appBarTitle,
      ),
      actions: actions ?? [],
    );
  }
}
```

I had to implement PreferredSizeWidget.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your widget to this

```
class WidgetAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final List<Widget> actions;

  WidgetAppBar({
    @required this.title,
    this.actions,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.colorAppBarBackground,
      elevation: 0,
      leadingWidth: Dimens.appBarLeadingWidth,
      centerTitle: false,
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: Styles.appBarTitle,
      ),
      actions: actions ?? []
    );
  }
}
```

The height of the Appbar will automatically change based on widgets inside. Don't force it

Comment: Hi @Matteo Antolini, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I do want to customise my AppBar height so I need the PreferredSize. I tried changing it to StatelessWidget while returning PreferredSize and it gives an error: The argument type 'WidgetAppBar' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget'.

Comment: You can add `bottom: SizedBox(height: height)`

Comment: Hi @Matteo Antolini, I figured it out. Posted the answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Also, @MAtteo Antolini, thanks for the actions: actions ?? [], saved me some future debugging.